# Chat between 2 different applications using firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a marketplace and want to provide the chat feature to customers and vendors. There are 2 separate apps for customer (App1) and vendors (App2). The idea is when a customer on App1 sends message to a vendor on App2 the message is received on App2 and the vendor can reply back. Can we do this in FIREBASE?
Front-end -> React-native
Back-end -> ASP.NET

Comment: Please share codes, what you tried. It will help you to learn more and also help us to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question is  little bit wide but technicaly you can share any kind of data between two apps using the Firebase REST API or even the Firebase Admin SDK. We use in your compay both solution depending on what task the need to accomplishe.

In your case because both Apps would need to send data to each other both of them would need to have an REST API to send and receive data.

If you plan to use a single Firebase Project for both apps you can just use the Firebase Client SDKs to communicate to the same Firebase Projekt trough different apps. A single Firebase project can have multiple Apps on multiple and same platforms and languages.